# Assign dynamic array values to the canvajs graph data in vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to populate canvajs graph using random array value. I am using Veujs2 library to implement the template to display the graph data. Please find the below file which i have pasted with the code.

```
import {Line} from 'vue-chartjs'

export default Line.extend({
  created () {
    this.generateRandomArray()

    setInterval(function () {
      this.generateRandomArray()
    }.bind(this), 1000)
  },
  methods: {
    generateRandomArray: function () {
    this.dataForServerOne = Array.from({ length: 7 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40))
    this.dataForServerTwo = Array.from({ length: 7 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40))
    console.log(this.dataForServerOne + ' = ' + this.dataForServerTwo)
  }
},
data: () => {
  return {
    dataForServerOne: [],
    dataForServerTwo: []
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.renderChart({
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Server One',
      backgroundColor: '#FC2525',
      // data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
      data: this.dataForServerOne
    },
    {
      label: 'Server Two',
      backgroundColor: '#05CBE1',
      data: this.dataForServerTwo
    }
  ]
 }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
}
```

})

In generateRandomArray() i have the dataForX variable value, i am not able to use this variable inside the renderchart function.

Comment: Are you sure [reactive data](http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=example) is supported by your library?

Comment: @MatJ - I am using chartjs as package with vue(Vue-chartjs), i hope it should support the reactive data.

Comment: Did you checked the link? Is it the same library? Then, I've got news for you.

Comment: Yes i am using the same library @Mat J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
created () {
  this.generateRandomArray()
},
methods: {
  generateRandomArray: () => {
  var dataForX = Array.from({ length: 7 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40))
}
```

With

```
data(){
  return {
    dataForX: Array.from({ length: 7 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40))
  }
}
```

Then fetch it using `this.dataForX`

Comment: This solution works to display data first time. I would like to display the random number every second. I have used setInterval inside data but it doesn't work. Can you please help me how to retrieve data for every second.

Comment: In that case, you want to call your `generateRandomArray` method every second.  But instead of `var dataForX =` you want `this.dataForX =` so it will update the property on your component.

Comment: Update the code with setInterval but still the value is not updating inside the view. Only one time it was updating the view. Then every second view is not updating but the code is executing every second i verified with console.log.

Comment: Make sure your interval function runs in the scope of your Vue component using bind . setInterval(function(){}.bind(this));

Comment: I have already using the bind(this) in the setInterval, please check the code i have updated. Still not able to see the data changes in view.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try declaring `data: () => {dataForServerOne:[], dataForServerTwo:[]} in your component.  Things should be declared if you want them to be reactive.

Comment: I have update the code with as you mentioned, but still the view is not update with the new data.